# What is the expected number of wins in this game?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's imagine a two player game where a player rolls a dice and then can keep the first score or decide to re-roll to get his/her final score.

Is there a general formula for the average expected number of points against a player who does the 'common sense' thing and re-rolls if they get less than $\frac{n}{2}+1$, where $n$ is the dice size.  Each player fixes their re-roll value before the game, it is then unchanged.

e.g. 6 sided dice, 3 example games  (...means re-rolls and uses second roll).  player 1 re-rolls if the score is less than 4, r(1)=4.  player 2 re-rolls if the score is less than 5, r(2)=5.

game 1)  player 1 rolls 2 ....5   player 2 rolls 3 ...1   result (5,1) 1 point to player 1

game 2)   player 1 rolls 4.    Player 2 rolls 4...5   result (4,5) 1 point to player 2

game 3)  player 1 rolls 6 .   Player 2 rolls 3 ...6   result (6,6) 0.5 points to both players

Average score $1.5/3=0.5$ for each player

---

The work done so far is in the answer section below, but it would be interesting if a general result for the expected average points could be found, in terms of the dice size $n$, and re-roll if the score is less than $r_1$ for player 1 and $r_2$ for player 2.

Comment: The chosen re-roll point will affect both the distribution of a player's score and their expected score.  When another player is involved, the distribution matters.

Comment: @ Henry yes, I'll edit to make clear that the players don't see each others rolls when deciding their re-roll choice  - it's made beforehand and fixed

Comment: My point was that, in another game, if you always roll a $5$ while I roll a $6$ with probability $\frac23$ and $1$ with probability $\frac13$, then obviously you have a higher expected roll but I am more likely to win (by a small amount, while when you win it is by a much larger amount)

Comment: @Henry  Yes, thanks,  that kind of thing probably leads to the surprising way that it's best to re-roll 5s (8 sided dice game), even though most people would keep a 5.  I was wondering whether it's possible to generalise this and get to a formula that predicts the 129/256 and other things

Comment: To be even more clear: a player does not know the opponent's first roll when deciding whether to make their second roll? Or equivalently, they're not really deciding each time, but inputting a constant re-roll threshold which will then take effect for them in each round?

Comment: @aschepler  yes, they are inputting a constant re-roll threshold once it's been decided at the beginning of the match. i.e both decide separately before the first game, without knowing anything about the others choice, then it stays constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that each side of the dice has the same probability $\frac 1n$ to be rolled.
Let $r\le n$ be a positive integer and a player rerolls if the score is less than $r$.
Then the player rerolls with probability $\frac{r-1}{n}$. So the probability $p_{i,r}$ that
the player rolled $i$ is $\frac{r-1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n}=\frac{r-1}{n^2}$, if $i\le r-1$, and $\frac 1n+\frac{r-1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n}=\frac{n+r-1}{n^2}$, if $i\ge r$. Thus for a positive number $j\le n$,
the probability $P_{j,r}$ that the player rolled more than $j$ is $\frac{(n+r-1)(n-j)}{n^2}$, if
if $j\ge r-1$, and $1-\frac{(r-1)j}{n^2}$, if $j\le r-1$.

Suppose that $r_1\le r_2\le n$ be positive integers, Player 1 re-rolls if the score is less than $r_1$, and Player 2 re-rolls if the score is less than $r_2$. Then the average score for Player 1 is

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_{j,r_2} (P_{j,r_1}+\frac 12 p_{j,r_1})=$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{r_1-1} p_{j,r_2} (P_{j,r_1}+\frac 12 p_{j,r_1})+
\sum_{j=r_1}^{r_2-1} p_{j,r_2} (P_{j,r_1}+\frac 12 p_{j,r_1})+
\sum_{j=r_2}^{n} p_{j,r_2} (P_{j,r_1}+\frac 12 p_{j,r_1})=$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{r_1-1} \frac{r_2-1}{n^2} \left(1-\frac{(r_1-1)j}{n^2}+\frac 12\cdot \frac{r_1-1}{n^2}\right)+
\sum_{j=r_1}^{r_2-1} \frac{r_2-1}{n^2} \left(\frac{(n+r_1-1)(n-j)}{n^2}+\frac 12 \cdot \frac{n+r_1-1}{n^2}\right)+
\sum_{j=r_2}^{n} \frac{n+r_2-1}{n^2} \left(\frac{(n+r_1-1)(n-j)}{n^2}+\frac 12 \cdot \frac{n+r_1-1}{n^2}\right)=$$

$$\frac 1{2n^4}\left((r_2-1)\sum_{j=1}^{r_1-1}\left(2n^2-2(r_1-1)j+r_1-1\right)+
(r_2-1)\sum_{j=r_1}^{r_2-1}  \left(2(n+r_1-1)(n-j)+n+r_1-1\right)+
(n+r_2-1) \sum_{j=r_2}^{n} \left(2(n+r_1-1)(n-j)+n+r_1-1\right)
\right)=
$$

$$\frac 1{2n^4}\left(2(r_1-1)(r_2-1)n^2+ (r_2-1)(r_1-1)\sum_{j=1}^{r_1-1}\left(1-2j\right)+
(r_2-1)(n+r_1-1)\sum_{j=r_1}^{r_2-1}  \left(2(n-j)+1\right)+
(n+r_2-1)(n+r_1-1)\sum_{j=r_2}^{n} \left(2(n-j)+1\right)
\right)=
$$

$$\frac 1{2n^4}\left(2(r_1-1)(r_2-1)n^2+ (r_2-1)(r_1-1)\left((r_1-1)-(r_1-1)r_1\right)+
(r_2-1)(n+r_1-1)\left(((r_2-1)-r_1+1)(2n+1)-(r_2-1)r_2+(r_1-1)r_1\right)+
(n+r_2-1)(n+r_1-1)\left((n-r_2+1)(2n+1)-n(n+1)+(r_2-1)r_2\right)
\right)=
$$

$$\frac 1{2n^4}\left(2(r_1-1)(r_2-1)n^2-(r_2-1)(r_1-1)^3+
(r_2-1)(n+r_1-1)(r_2-r_1)(2n+1+1-r_1-r_2)+
(n+r_2-1)(n+r_1-1)(n-r_2+1)(2n+1-n-r_2)
\right)=
$$

$$\frac 1{2n^4}\left(2(r_1-1)(r_2-1)n^2-(r_2-1)(r_1-1)^3+
(r_2-1)(n+r_1-1)(r_2-r_1)(2n+2-r_1-r_2)+
(n+r_2-1)(n+r_1-1)(n-r_2+1)^2
\right)=
$$

$$\frac 12+\frac {r_1-r_2}{2n^3}\left(n^2-(r_2-1)n-(r_1-1)(r_2-1)\right)$$

(the last step was done with Mathcad).

Comment: Well done Alex.  Your answer seems right and it's been checked against the numbers generated by computer program in the other answer, also using $n=17$,   $r_1=12$ and $r_2=15$  also $r_1=6$ and $r_1=13$.  It also explains why the two $0.5$ values occur for $r_1 = \frac{n}{2}+1$ when $r_1 = r_2$  and $r_2 = \frac{2}{3}n$, from solving the bracket on the right of your final answer being equal to zero. Leading actually to $r_2 = \frac{2}{3}n+1$

Comment: @JohnHunter Thanks for your kind words. Although I hope that in my calculations are no errors, the chances for them are rater big. So verifications of my calculations, in particular, numeric, are welcome. By the way, as far as I see, when $r_1=\frac n2+1$ then to annulate the bracket we need $r_2=\frac 23n+1$.

Comment: Yes, and it all leads to the maximum expected score when $r_2 = \frac{7}{12} n +1$, bounty will be awarded before too long, when the system allows

Comment: ... and following on from your answer, a simplified formula has now been obtained that gives the expectations for player 2 against a player 1 who has $r_1 = \frac{n}{2} +1$.  It's in the comments of the other answer, where the formula can be compared to the results of the computer run.

Comment: Hi @AlexRavsky, the final formula you provide for the expected points given $n,r_1,r_2$ unfortunately seems to work only for some cases. For example for $n = 6, r_1 = 3, r_2 = 4$ is correct while for example for $n = 10, r_1 = 7, r_2 = 3$ you get 0.636 while I get 0.556. Please check my answer to see if I made some mistakes, although the simulation via Montecarlo agrees with my formula. PS: your formula for the expected points is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{r_1-r_2}{2n^3}(n^2-(r_2-1)n-(r_1-1)(r_2-1))$; is that correct?

Comment: On Alex's behalf:  He mentions that his formula uses $r_1$ <$ r_2$ <$n$ .  If done this way his formula for player 1 gives 0.444 and so for player 2 1-0.444=0.556 like yours-   Equivalent of player 1 getting 0.556 if you have the $r$ values the other way around

Comment: Oh, my bad. In fact our result are the same.. Sorry Alex!

Answer (score 2):

Because the players don't see each other's actions, this is actually a single player game with 2 different strategies. The common sense first strategy is to re-roll if the first roll's value, 1 to $n$, was $<1+n/2$. The second, generalized strategy tries to maximize the expectation value (EV) and re-rolls if the first value was $<t+n/2$ searching for a better threshold $t$.

For even $n$, the face values $(f_1)$ for games with one roll
are (t+n/2), (t+1+n/2), .. (n), each with probability $1/n$, $n\ge 2t$.
The face values $(f_1,f_2)$ for games with two rolls are
(1,1), (1,2), .. (1,n), (2,1), (2,2), ... (2,n), .. (n/2+t-1,1), (n/2+t-1,2), .. (n/2+t-1,n) each with probability  $1/n^2$, $n\ge 4-2t$. So
the EV of the strategy is
$$
\frac{1}{n}(t+\frac{n}{2}+t+1+\frac{n}{2}+\cdots +n)
+\frac{1}{n^2}(1+2+\cdots +n+1+2+\cdots +n+)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{(n+2-2t)(3n+2t)}{8}
+\frac{1}{n^2}(\frac{n}{2}+t-1)(1+2+\cdots +n)
$$
$$
=\frac{(3n+2t)(n+2-2t)}{8n}
+\frac{1}{n^2}(\frac{n}{2}+t-1)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
=(5n^2+4n-4t^2+8t-4)/(8n)
$$
for even $n$, $n\ge \max(2t,4-2t)$.
The same calculation for the first strategy for odd $n$:
The face values $(f_1)$ for one roll
are (t+(n+1)/2), (t+1+(n+1)/2), .. (n), each with probability $1/n$, $n\ge 2t+1$.
The face values for two rolls are
(1,1), (1,2), .. (1,n), (2,1), (2,2), ... (2,n), .. ((n+1)/2+t-1,1), ((n+1)/2+t-1,2), .. ((n+1)/2+t-1,n) with probability $1/n^2$, $n\ge 3-2t$.
So
the EV of the strategy is
$$
\frac{1}{n}(t+\frac{n+1}{2}+t+1+\frac{n+1}{2}+\cdots +n)
+\frac{1}{n^2}(1+2+\cdots +n+1+2+\cdots +n+)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{(3n+1+2t)(n+1-2t)}{8}
+\frac{1}{n^2}(\frac{n+1}{2}+t-1)(1+2+\cdots +n)
$$
$$
=\frac{(3n+1+2t)(n+1-2t)}{8n}
+\frac{1}{n^2}(\frac{n+1}{2}+t-1)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
=\frac{5n^2+4n-1-4t^2+4t}{8n}
$$
for odd $n\ge \max(2t+1,3-2t)$.
By numerical evaluation one sees that the highest EV are for $t=1$ if $n$ is even, and that the highest (same) EV are for $t=0$ and $t=1$ if $n$ is odd.
Explicitly for $n=1,2,3,4,...$ these are 1, 7/4, 7/3, 3, 18/5, 17/4, 34/7, 11/2, 55/9, 27/4,...

One can split this statistics by providing a probability $p_t(s)$ of scoring $s$ for the single user game. For even $n$, scores $s=1,2,...,t+n/2-1$ are achieved having rolled twice: probability of the first (discarded) score is $(t+n/2-1)/n$ and probability of the final score is $1/n$, in succession $(t+n/2-1)/n\times(1/n)$. Scores $s=t+n/2,t+n/2+1,..n$ are reached by either rolling once (probability $1/n$) or rolling twice, probability $(t+n/2-1)/n \times (1/n)$, total $[(t+n/2-1)/n+1]/n$.
The probability $(t+n/2-1)/n$ means zero in all expressions if the value is negative and 1 if the value is larger than 1, effectively
$$
q_t(n) \equiv \min(\max( \frac{t+\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor-1)}{n},0),1) ,
$$
$$
q_r(n) \equiv \min(\max(\frac{r-1}{n},0),1) .
$$
For odd $n$ scores $s=1,2,..., t+(n+1)/2-1$ are achieved having rolled twice: probability of the first (discarded) score $(t+(n+1)/2-1)/n$ and $1/n$ of the second, in succession $(t+(n+1)/2-1)/n\times(1/n)$. Scores $s=t+(n+1)/2,...,n$ have probability $[(t+(n+1)/2-1)/n+1]/n$, with equivalent interpretation/clipping of $[t+(n+1)/2-1]/n$.

$$
p_t(s) =
q_t(n)/n\wedge 1\le s \le t+\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor-1 ,
$$
$$
p_r(s) =
q_r(n)/n\wedge 1\le s \le r-1 
$$
and
$$
p_t(s) = q_t(n)/n+1/n\wedge t+\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor \le s \le n. 
$$
$$
p_r(s) = q_r(n)/n+1/n\wedge r \le s \le n. 
$$
For the 2 player game one must "convolve" these two distributions (with 2 different $t_1$, $t_2$ of the two players)
and (say) 1 for each win of player 1 to compute a probability that player 1 wins. In detail: A $n\times n$ matrix tableau
for rows of the scores $s$ of the first player and columns for the scores $s$ of the second player contains
the products $p_{t_1}(s_1)p_{t_2}(s_2)$, the probability of the joined outcome;
one must basically weigh these products by $1/2$ on the diagonal (draws of the game),
weigh them by 1 in the lower left triangular area (where 1 wins) and by 0 in the upper right area (where 1 loses).
The winning probability for player 1 is
$$
P =  
\sum_{{s_1}=1}^n \sum_{s_2=1}^{s_1-1}  p_{t_1}(s_1)p_{t_2}(s_2)
+\frac12 \sum_{{s_1}=1}^n p_{t_1}(s_1)p_{t_2}(s_1)
$$
$$
=  
\sum_{{s_1}=1}^n \sum_{s_2=1}^{s_1-1}  p_{r_1}(s_1)p_{r_2}(s_2)
+\frac12 \sum_{{s_1}=1}^n p_{r_1}(s_1)p_{r_2}(s_1).
$$

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. But it's unclear whether it's the same as the two player game.  E.g. for n=8  player 2 must play against player 1 who re-rolls if the score is less than 5, and compare his/her score against player 1s score each time.  For a large number of games we have average expected points of $\frac{127}{256}$ and $\frac{129}{256}$ for players 1 and 2, if player 2 re-rolls if the score is less than 6, surprisingly, even though EVs are 5.5 and $5\frac{7}{16}$.  For n=6 EV is 4.25 best and 4.1666 if re-roll less than 5, but against each other,  r(1)=4 vs r(2) =5 gives $0.5$, $0.5$

Comment: My guess: The surprise effect is caused by the fact that a losing (say) game of player 1 counts as "losing once" independent of by how far the losing score differs from the winning score. That means if player 2 knows that player 1 uses a threshold of $t=1$, he may opt to be even more "aggressive" by using a threshold of $t=2$. It's then that the gradients of the expectation values come into pl
ay, not just the expectation values themselves.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what happens.   Your section on the two player game seems fine.  A computer program on a similar thing was written and produced the probabilities of winning, examples in the other answer.  Do you think it's possible to obtain a formula that reproduces those numbers using just $n$, $r1$ and $r2$?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
This is more an observation that might be of some interest than an answer to the question actually asked.  Credit to [Alex Ravsky](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71850/alex-ravsky) for identifying a couple of embarrassing blunders in my earlier presentations of this observation.

If you give *both* players a free choice of re-roll threshold, instead of fixing one of their thresholds at $\ \frac{n}{2}+1\ $, then the game becomes a two-player, [constant-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory#Zero-sum_/_non-zero-sum) game with [incomplete information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory#Perfect_information_and_imperfect_information).  Both players have the same optimal pure strategy, which is to choose the threshold to be either $\ \lfloor (\varphi-1)n\rfloor+1\ $  or $\ \lfloor (\varphi-1)n\rfloor+2\ ,$ where $\ \varphi\ed\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\ $ is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). If $\ \ell\ed\lfloor(\varphi-1)n\rfloor\ $ and $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2<0\ $ then the optimal threshold is $\ \ell+1\ ,$ whereas if $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2>$$\,0\ $ then the optimal threshold is $\ \ell+2\ .$ If $\ n^2-n-(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2$$\,=0\ ,$ then both $\ \ell+1\ $ and $\ \ell+2\ $ are optimal thresholds$.^\color{red}{\dagger}$

This strategy guarantees that a player's expected score is always at least $\ \frac{1}{2}\ ,$ and will be strictly greater than $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ if his or her opponent doesn't choose an optimal threshold. By "re-roll threshold" here, I mean the values $\ r_1, r_2\ $ specified by the OP as those of the first throw *below* which the respective players will re-roll. Thus, if the value of player $\ i$'s first throw is $\ r_i\ $ or more, he or she will *not* re-roll.

For $\ n=6\ ,$ $\ \ell=3\ $ and $\ n^2-n-(n+1)\ell-\ell^2=$$\,36\,-$$\,6\,-$$\,21\,-$$\,9$$\,=0\ ,$ so both $\ 4\ $ and $\ 5\ $ are optimal thresholds.

**Details of Calculation**

Let the first player's expected score when the players' re-roll thresholds are $\ r_1, r_2\ $ be
$$
\frac{1}{2}+V\big(r_1-1, r_2-1)\label{e1}\tag{1}\ .
$$
From [Alex Ravsky's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797130/what-is-the-expected-number-of-wins-in-this-game/4799149#4799149), we know that  for $\ s_2\ge s_1\ $
$$
V\big(s_1,s_2\big)=\frac {(s_1-s_2)}{2n^3}\left(n^2-s_2n-s_1s_2\right)\ .
$$
If $\ r_1\ge r_2\ ,$ then by symmetry the second player's expected score is
$$
\frac{1}{2}+V\big(r_2-1, r_1-1\big)
$$
and therefore the first player's expected score is
\begin{align}
1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+V\big(r_2-1, r_1-1\big)\right)&=\frac{1}{2}-V\big(r_2-1, r_1-1\big)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+V\big(r_1-1,r_2-1\big)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, for $\ s_2\ge s_1\ $
\begin{align}
V\big(s_1,s_2\big)&=-V\big(s_2,s_1\big)\\
&=\frac{\big(s_1-s_2\big)}{2n_3}\big(n^2-s_1n-s_1s_2\big)\ .\label{e2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
Combining equations (\ref{e1}) and (\ref{e2}) we have
$$
V\big(s_1,s_2\big)=\cases{\frac {(s_1-s_2)}{2n^3}\left(n^2-s_2n-s_1s_2\right)&for $\ s_2\ge s_1$\\
\frac {(s_1-s_2)}{2n^3}\left(n^2-s_1n-s_1s_2\right)&for $\ s_1\ge s_2\ $.}
$$

If $\ n^2-n-(n+1)\ell-\ell^2\le0\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
V\big(\ell,s_2\big)&=\cases{\frac {\big(\ell-s_2\big)\big(n^2-(n+\ell)s_2\big)}{2n^3}&if $\ s_2\ge\ell$\\
\frac {\big(\ell-s_2\big)\big(n^2-\ell n-\ell s_2\big)}{2n^3}&if $\ s_2\le\ell\ .$}
\end{align}
For $\ s_2\ge\ell+1\ ,$ $\ \ell-s_2<0\ $ and
\begin{align}
n^2-(n+\ell)s_2&\le n^2-(n+\ell)(\ell+1)\\
&=n^2-n-(n+1)\ell-\ell^2\\
&\le0\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, $\ V\big(\ell,s_2\big)\ge0\ $ for $\ s_2\ge\ell+1\ ,$ with strict inequality whenever $\ n^2-n-(n+1)\ell-\ell^2<0\ .$

For $\ s_2\le\ell-1\ ,$ $\ \ell-s_2>0\ $ and
\begin{align}
n^2-\ell n -\ell s_2&>n^2-\ell n-\ell^2\\
&>n^2-(\varphi-1)n^2-(\varphi-1)^2n^2\\
&=n^2\big(1+\varphi-\varphi^2\big)\\
&=0\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, $\ V\big(\ell,s_2\big)>0\ $ for $\ s_2\le\ell-1\ $. It follows that $\ V\big(\ell,s_2\big)\ge0\ $ for all $\ s_2\ $ whenever $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2\le0\ ,$ with strict inequality whenever $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2<0\ $ and $\ s_2\ne\ell\ $, and hence that $\ \ell+1\ $ is an optimal threshold when $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2\le0\ $ and *uniquely* optimal when $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2<0\ .$

If $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2\ge0\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
V\big(\ell+1,s_2\big)&=\cases{\frac {\big(\ell+1-s_2\big)\big(n^2-(n+\ell+1)s_2\big)}{2n^3}&if $\ s_2\ge\ell+1$\\
\frac {\big(\ell+1-s_2\big)\big(n^2-(\ell+1)n-(\ell+1)s_2\big)}{2n^3}&if $\ s_2\le\ell+1\ .$}
\end{align}

For $\ s_2\ge\ell+2\ ,$ $\ \ell+1-s_2<0\ $ and
\begin{align}
n^2-(n+\ell+1)s_2&< n^2-(n+\ell+1)(\ell+1)\\
&=n^2-n(\ell+1)-(\ell+1)^2\\
&<n^2\big(1-(\varphi-1)-(\varphi-1)^2\big)\\
&=0\ .
\end{align}
Therefore $\ V\big(\ell+1,s_2\big)>0\ $ for $\ s_2\ge\ell+2\ $.

For $\ s_2\le\ell\ ,$ $\ \ell+1-s_2>0\ $ and
\begin{align}
n^2-(\ell+1)n-(\ell+1)s_2&\ge n^2-(\ell+1)n-(\ell+1)\ell\\
&=n^2-n-(n+1)\ell-\ell^2\\
&\ge0\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, $\ V\big(\ell+1,s_2\big)\ge0\ $ for $\ s_2\le\ell\ ,$ with strict inequality whenever $\ n^2-n-(n+1)\ell-\ell^2>0\ .$ It follows that $\ V\big(\ell+1,s_2\big)\ge0\ $ for all $\ s_2\ $ whenever $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2\ge0\ ,$ with strict inequality whenever $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2>0\ $ and $\ s_2\ne\ell+1\ $, and hence that $\ \ell+2\ $ is an optimal threshold when $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2\ge0\ $ and *uniquely* optimal when $\ n^2-$$\,n-$$\,(n+1)\ell-$$\,\ell^2>0\ .$

This completes the proof of the assertions made above about the optimal thresholds.

$\left.\right.^\color{red}{\dagger}$ This is very rare. It occurs if and only if $\ 5n^2-2n+1\ $ is a perfect square. The values of $\ n\ $ for which this is the case comprise the sequence [$\text{A}081016$](https://oeis.org/A081016) of the online encyclopedia of integer sequences. The only positive values of $\ n\ $ below one million for which it's the case are $\ 1,$$\,6,$$\,40,$$\,273,$$\,1870,$$\,12816,$$\,87841,$ and $\ 602070.$

Comment: Thankyou, Interesting observation!  I had imagined a single game, but to describe the 'expected average score' it was mentioned that it would be the average score if thousands of games were played, then an average of the points taken, with each player fixing their re-roll value beforehand.  For those interested, we could imagine e.g. 6 players, each with a 10 sided dice.  The optimal re-roll becomes higher up to 8 or 9, (unless you presume that the other players are aware of that and are each using re-roll of 9, then it's better to go lower)...but maybe all this would be another question!

Comment: For $\ m\ $ players, I'm pretty sure there will be a [Nash equilibrium](https://www.britannica.com/science/Nash-equilibrium) in which all the players have the same equilibrium strategy—with a form similar to that of the case $\ m=2\ $— that will guarantee them each a score of at least $\ \frac{1}{m}\ $.  If I can work out what it is, I'll add the details to my "answer".

Comment: As far as I see, $\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial s_1^2}\big(s_1,s_2\big)=\frac {-n-s_2}{n^3}$ when $\ s_2\ge s_1$. Also I guess that the last inequalities following the convexity and concavity should be reversed (I use the parabola $f(x)=x^2$ to remember where in these inequality should be ``$\le$'' or ``$\ge$''). But anyway,
I think that the function $V$ is incorrect, for instance, we should have $V\big(s_1,s_2\big)=\frac {(s_1-s_2)}{2n^3}\left(n^2-s_{\color\red 2}n-s_1s_2\right)$, when $s_2\ge s_1$.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky Many thanks for picking up the embarrassing blunders with the inequalities of convexity and concavity.  I think I've now managed to find the correct saddle point for the game. I'm still getting $\ V\big(s_1,s_2\big)=\frac{(s_1-s_2)}{2n^3}\left(n^2-\color{red}{s_1}n-s_1s_2\right)\ $ for $\ s_2\ge s_1\ $, however, so I've added my proposed derivation of that identity.  Is there still something that I'm missing?

Comment: The final formula in my answer is for $r_1{\color{red} \le} r_2$.

Comment: Thanks again.  I think the method I used to get the saddle point for the erroneous $\ V\ $ will stil work for the correct one.  The two optimal thresholds will remain the same, but the expression whose sign determines which of the two is optimal changes from $\ n^2-(n+1)\ell-\ell^2\ $ to $\ n^2-n-(n+1)\ell-\ell^2\ .$

Answer (score 0):

Here are some results.  Surprisingly in the example above, re-roll scores $4$ against $5$ both have expected average scores of $0.5$ and $0.5$

Also when the dice size is increased e.g. to $n=8$, a player with $r(2)=6$ (only keeping 6 or more), does better than the common sense $r(1)=5$ (only keeping 5 or more),  A computer program playing many times gave $0.4961$ vs $0.5039$, (player 1 vs player 2), even though the mean scores would be $5\frac{1}{2}$ and $5\frac{7}{16}$ (player 1 vs player 2).

Even though the mean is better for player 1, when the players play each other, player 2 does better.  That's counter-intuitive, but a sample space also gives $\frac{129}{256}$ for player 2

Instead of doing lots of tables, another program was written that works out the exact probabilities from sample spaces, just saving time.

There are some definite trends for all dice sizes $n$.  Against a player using a re-roll value of $r(1)=\frac{n}{2}+1$ , the best re-roll choice for player 2 is at about 60% of the dice size.  The expected score then is always about $0.5052$.

There is an approximately symmetrical distribution of the expected scores, between $0.5$ when $r(1)=r(2)$ peaking when $r(2)$ is about $0.6n$ then dropping back to $0.5$  when $r(2)$ is $\frac{2}{3}n$.

Here are some results from $n=24$ and $n=60$

[image: n=24]

[image: n=60]

Comment: John that's an amazing problem and I think I come up with a solution.. unfortunately now I have a lesson at my university, but I will post my attempt soon.

Comment: @ Luca Onnis, that would be good. After Alex's great answer, here is a simplified formula for when $r_1=\frac{n}{2}+1$, for the player 2 expectations (Alex's formula gives player 1), so that the match to the computer run above can more easily be checked it's $\frac{1}{8} (2+7X-6X^2)$ where $X=\frac{r_2-1}{n}$.  As well as the 0.5
 values, Alex's formula predicts the maximum at $\frac{7}{12}n$
 with the 0.5052... value being $\frac{97}{192}$

Comment: I have just posted my attempt with the general case for given $n,r_1,r_2$

Comment: @ Luca Onnis  Thankyou for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the number of faces of the dice and consider two player A and B with $r_A$ and $r_B$ defined respectively as $r_1$ and $r_2$. Let $X$ be the random variable with possible values $0,0.5,1$ (0 if $A$ loses, 0.5 if draw, 1 if $A$ wins). Let $Y_A$ and $Y_B$ be the "final" value of the dice (so $A$ wins if $Y_A > Y_B$). Let $D_1(A),D_2(A)$ be the value of the first roll and the value of the eventual second roll (made if $D_1(A) < r_A$), and similarly we define $D_1(B),D_2(B)$.

We now compute the density function of the discrete random variable $Y_A$ (and similarly for $Y_B$):

$$
P(Y_A = y_a) = P(Y_A = y_a, D_1(A) < r_A) + P(Y_A = y_a, D_1(A) \geq r_A) =  \\
=P(Y_A = y_a| D_1(A) < r_A) P(D_1(A) < r_A)+ P(Y_A = y_a| D_1(A) \geq r_A)P(D_1(A) \geq r_A)
$$
by law of total probabilities. But furthermore $$P(Y_A = y_a| D_1(A) < r_A) = P(D_2(A) = y_a)$$ and $$P(Y_A = y_a| D_1(A) \geq r_A) = \begin{cases}0 \mbox{ if $y_a < r_A$} \\ \frac{1}{n-r_A+1} \mbox{ if $y_a\geq r_A$}\end{cases}$$
and $P(D_1(A) < r_A) = \frac{r_A-1}{n}$ and $P(D_1(A) \geq r_A) = \frac{n-r_A+1}{n}$.

Using this facts we find out that:
$$
P(Y_A = y_a) = \begin{cases} \frac{r_A-1}{n^2} \mbox{ if $y_a < r_A$} \\ \frac{r_A-1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n} \mbox{ if $y_a \geq r_A$}\\ \end{cases}
$$
(Note how the sum of these probabilities from $y_a = 1$ to $y_a = n$ is of course always equal to 1).

Now we observe that A wins if $Y_A > Y_B$ and draws if $Y_A = Y_B$ , so we need the joint density function of $(Y_A,Y_B)$ in order to compute the desired probabilities.

Luckily $Y_A$ and $Y_B$ are indipedent variables and so their joint density function is the product of the marginals:

$$
P(Y_A = y_a, Y_B = y_b) = \begin{cases} \frac{(r_A-1)(r_B-1)}{n^4} \mbox{ $y_a < r_A $and $y_b < r_B$} \\ \frac{r_A-1}{n^2}[\frac{r_B-1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}] \mbox{ if $y_a < r_A$ and $y_b \geq r_B$} \\ \frac{r_B-1}{n^2}[\frac{r_A-1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}] \mbox{ if $y_a \geq r_A$ and $y_b < r_B$} \\ [\frac{r_A-1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}][\frac{r_B-1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}] \mbox{ if $y_a \geq r_A$ and $y_b \geq r_B$}\end{cases}
$$

And finally:

$$
P(Y_A-Y_B > 0) = \sum_{(y_a,y_b)\in\{1,\dots,n\}^2: y_a > y_b}P(Y_A = y_a, Y_B = y_b) = \sum_{y_a = 2}^{n}\sum_{y_b = 1}^{y_a-1}P(Y_A = y_a, Y_B = y_b)
$$

and

$$
P(Y_A-Y_B = 0) = \sum_{(y_a,y_b)\in\{1,\dots,n\}^2: y_a = y_b}P(Y_A = y_a, Y_B = y_b) = \sum_{y = 1}^{n}P(Y_A = y, Y_B = y)
$$

using the R software, I made the following code which compares the approximation of these probababilities using Montecarlo simulation and the theoretical ones:

```
n = 6
rA = 3
rB = 4
it = 20000
cont = 0
# Montecarlo simulation
for(i in 1:it) {
  D1A = sample(1:n,1)
  if(D1A < rA) {
    D2A = sample(1:n,1)
    yA = D2A
  }
  else if(D1A >= rA) {
    yA = D1A
  }
  D1B = sample(1:n,1)
  if(D1B < rB) {
    D2B = sample(1:n,1)
    yB = D2B
  }
  else if(D1B >= rB) {
    yB = D1B
  }
  if(yA - yB > 0) {
    cont[i] = 1 
  }
  else if(yA - yB == 0) {
    cont[i] = 1/2
  }
  else if(yA - yB < 0) {
    cont[i] = 0
  }
}
PAwins = mean(cont == 1)
Pdraw = mean(cont == 1/2)
PBwins = mean(cont == 0)

# theoretical value
PyAyB = matrix(rep(0,n^2),n,n)
for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:n) {
    if(i < rA && j < rB) {
      PyAyB[i,j] = ((rA-1)*(rB-1))/n^4
    }
    else if(i < rA && j >= rB) {
      PyAyB[i,j] = ((rA-1)/n^2)*((rB-1)/n^2+1/n)
    }
    else if(i >= rA && j < rB) {
      PyAyB[i,j] = ((rA-1)/n^2+1/n)*((rB-1)/n^2)
    }
    else if(i >= rA && j >= rB) {
      PyAyB[i,j] = ((rA-1)/n^2+1/n)*((rB-1)/n^2+1/n)
    }
  }
}
PAwinstheoretical = 0
for(i in 2:n) {
  for(j in 1:(i-1)) {
    PAwinstheoretical = PAwinstheoretical + PyAyB[i,j]
  }
}
Pdrawtheoretical = 0
for(i in 1:n) {
  Pdrawtheoretical = Pdrawtheoretical + PyAyB[i,i]
}
PBwinstheoretical = 1 - PAwinstheoretical - Pdrawtheoretical
```

Here I used $n = 6$, $r_A = 3$ and $r_B = 4$ and I have obtained that A wins with probability 0.375, draws with probability 0.1944444 and loses with probability 0.4305556.

To compute the expected value $\mathbb{E}(X)$ , simply used the definition:
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = 1\cdot P(Y_A > Y_B) + 0.5\cdot P(Y_A = Y_B) + 0\cdot P(Y_A < Y_B)
$$

Add this line of code to the other script to compute the expected points in 1 round:

```
expectedpoints = 1*PAwinstheoretical+0.5*Pdrawtheoretical
```

Note that the expected points in $k$ round is $k\cdot\mathbb{E}(X)$ for the linearity of the operator of the expected value.

Using the formulas I provided I think that for every $n$ then the maximum expected points for the player A is reached using $r_A = \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1$ and $r_B = 1$. For even $n$ this maximum is exactly equal to $\frac{5}{8} = 0.625$.

Comment: Yes,  it seems right, your 0.194444 times 0.5 plus 0.43055555 matches the expected average score for player 2 from the other computer program.   Alex has found a formula, you can check your program against that formula if you want...

Comment: Of course, I will do it as soon as I arrive home. My program is based on the theoretical result I proved in the post, in the sense that it compares the approssimation given by montecarlo simulation and the exact value of the probability.

Comment: @JohnHunter I think that Alex's formula unfortunately works only for some specific values of $n,r_1,r_2$, for example for $n = 10, r_1 = 7, r_2 = 3$ we obtain different values, although mine has (apart from the calculations I made) the evidence of the Montecarlo simulation I provide in the R script.

Comment: On Alex's behalf:  He mentions that his formula uses $r_1$ <$ r_2$ <$n$ .  If done this way his formula for player 1 gives 0.444 and so for player 2 1-0.444=0.556 like yours-   Equivalent of player 1 getting 0.556 if you have the $r$ values the other way around